# Collect Device information in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin, I would like to know how we can obtain current device information in Xamarin Cross-Platform project ? I found System.Configuration API but how to use the same is little bit confusing to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get basic information from `Xamarin.Forms.Device` such as the `TargetIdiom` (Phone, Tablet, Desktop), and the `OS` (iOS, Android, WinPhone, Windows, Other).

You can get extended device information like screen width, screen height etc if you take a look at `XLabs` that exposes more information for the actual device, link [here](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/Samples/XLabs.Sample/Pages/Services/ExtendedDeviceInfoPage.cs).

Comment: Thanks Pete, but i cant find any reference of Xamarin.Forms.Device in my Portable class library project, did i missed something?

Comment: Do you have Xamarin.Forms installed on your PCL project?  Check NuGet to ensure its also installed on the PCL as well.

Comment: Yes,I can see Xamarin.Forms installed in my PCL. Thus i have Xamarin.Forms.Core, Xamarin.Forms.Platform & Xamarin.Forms.Xaml present under references section.

Comment: So if you type 'Xamarin.Forms.' your intellisense should populate with an entry also available for 'Device'.  If your still stuck, send the solution to me and I will take a quick look, my details are on my profile.

Comment: Ohh, I got it.It is taking some time after adding the nuget package to the PCL, now i can see the intellisense is showing me the expected reference.